# Need to display city from IP address by using python

Tags: python, pandas, geocoder

I've dataframe with name loaddata1 with column "IP_Adress" containing IP's in it and I want another column with name "city" which will display corresponding city based on Ip_adress.
Can some suggest proper code. I've used below code but its not working. Also "IP_Adress" column is blank for some of record.

---

`loaddata1 = pd.DataFrame({'ip': loaddata1['IP_Adress']})`

`loaddata1['city'] = loaddata1.loc[loaddata1['ip'].notna(), 'ip'].apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).city) print(loaddata1['IP_Adress'], loaddata1['city'])`
`

---

Still getting Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuEdy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iy3F.png)

Comment: remove .city after loaddatea1['city']

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import geocoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': ['151.101.1.69', '151.101.1.69']})

df['city'] = df['ip'].apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).city)
```

For a faster run, you can combine it with [`pandarallel`](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel):

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
import geocoder

pandarallel.initialize()

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': ['151.101.1.69', '151.101.1.69']})

df['city'] = df['ip'].parallel_apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).city)
```

output:

```
             ip           city
0  151.101.1.69  San Francisco
1  151.101.1.69  San Francisco
```

Comment: I've tried below code still giving me error.

***
`from pandarallel import pandarallel`




`import geocoder`

`pandarallel.initialize()`

`loaddata1 = pd.DataFrame({'ip': loaddata1['IP_Adress']})`

`loaddata1['city'] = loaddata1['ip'].parallel_apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).city)`
***

Comment: Please try first the **first code** (the `pandarallel` one is a bonus). Then provide the full error as edit to your question

Comment: updated above code with reference to your code still giving me error. Attached screenshot as well.

Comment: If you got this, you didn't get it from my code. Do you have NaNs in your data? You might want to apply the function to only the non-NA subset: `df['city'] = df.loc[df['ip'].notna(), 'ip'].parallel_apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).city)`

Comment: Yes, I do have NaNs in IP_Adress column. Can you please suggest how to deal with that.

Comment: I just did in my previous comment.

Comment: please refer above code and screenshot of error. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory, you're performing too many requests to the online service are being blocked. You should then probably write a custom function to perform a limited number of request per second/minute. It feels to me out of the scope of this question which was on the syntax to be used.